# Send Email based on Sku of product ordered

Tags: magento-1.8, php, transactional-mail

I'm trying to send an email to notify us if a specific sku is ordered.  I've created the following module, but I'm not receiving the email.

**app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MyCompany_MyModule>
        <version>0.1.0</version>   
    </MyCompany_MyModule>
</modules>

<adminhtml>
    <models>
        <mycompanymymodule>
            <class>MyModule_Model</class>
        </mycompanymymodule>
    </models>
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_after>
            <observers>
                <mycompany_mymodule_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>sendEmail</method>
                </mycompany_mymodule_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Model/Observer.php**:

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer 
{
    public function sendEmail($observer) {
        $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $itemCollection = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
        if($product->getSku() == 'SKU') {
             $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
             $mail->setToName('Your name');
             $mail->setToEmail('myemail@mycompany.com');
             $mail->setBody('Order number '.$order->getIncrementId().' has items that need action');
             $mail->setSubject('Order '.$order->getIncrementId().' needs attention');
             $mail->setFromName('Your from name');
             $mail->setFromEmail('customerservice@mycompany.com');
             $mail->setType('text');

                try {
                    $mail->send();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::log($e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I checked my error log file but not seeing anything.  I've also `sales_order_save_after` for my event observer.

I still get the order confirmation email after ordering that particular sku but not the extra notification email.  Not sure where I went wrong?

**EDIT**

I now have this working, I've edited the code above with proper changes.  However, now I'm receiving my notification email twice instead of just one time.

Comment: How to use district in if condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the duplicate email by changing my observer FROM `sales_order_save_after` TO `sales_order_place_after`

My final code looks like this

**app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/etc/config.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <MyCompany_MyModule>
        <version>0.1.0</version>   
    </MyCompany_MyModule>
</modules>

<adminhtml>
    <models>
        <mycompanymymodule>
            <class>MyModule_Model</class>
        </mycompanymymodule>
    </models>
    <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <mycompany_mymodule_model_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>sendEmail</method>
                </mycompany_mymodule_model_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/MyCompany/MyModule/Model/Observer.php**:

```
class MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer 
{
    public function sendEmail($observer) {
        $orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getId();
        $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
        $itemCollection = $order->getItemsCollection();
        foreach($itemCollection as $item) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
        if($product->getSku() == 'SKU') {
             $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
             $mail->setToName('Your name');
             $mail->setToEmail('myemail@mycompany.com');
             $mail->setBody('Order number '.$order->getIncrementId().' has items that need action');
             $mail->setSubject('Order '.$order->getIncrementId().' needs attention');
             $mail->setFromName('Your from name');
             $mail->setFromEmail('customerservice@mycompany.com');
             $mail->setType('text');

                try {
                    $mail->send();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    Mage::log($e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change scope from **`<adminhtml>`** to **`<global>`**.

**Edit:**

If you want to fire mail  only when order place,then ***you can use any of below events which are fire one time for everyOrder***

- [checkout_submit_all_after](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3139/4564)
- **`sales_order_place_before`**
- **`sales_order_place_after`** Already use

### You have done some mistake.

- Model have define for  admin area **`<adminhtml>`** create.It should
  be  for  global area **`<global>`**..

  `<global> <!-- It should be global from adminhml -->
      <models>
          <mycompanymymodule>
              <class>MyModule_Model</class>
          </mycompanymymodule>
      </models>
  ...
  </global> <!-- It should be global from adminhml -->`
- As you have **define,the observer for admin area** that it have only firing for admin section that  mean if you `do anything  to an Order from backend/admin` then mail will fire

  ```
          <events>
              <sales_order_save_after>
                  <observers>
                      <mycompany_mymodule_model_observer>
                          <type>singleton</type>
                          <class>MyCompany_MyModule_Model_Observer</class>
                          <method>sendEmail</method>
                      </mycompany_mymodule_model_observer>
                  </observers>
              </sales_order_save_after>
          </events>
      </global>
  ```

**For duplicated mail on same sku:**

*Reason:*

- As you have using `sales_order_save_after` event  then **observer
  will run several  times** because of whenever  *save()* of
  `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` will call,your mail is fired.
- If a **configurable product id** is place then as per as your code
  **two mails will fire be  for single configurable products**.Beause of when a **configurable product place then two rows** will be insert
  at *sales_order_item*.

  One have Parent product id & child product sku

  Another is Child product id & child product sku

  **So,you need to prevent it by**

  ```
  if ($item->isDeleted() || $item->getParentItemId()) {
  continue; //
   $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
  ```

Comment: Thanks Amit!  So this particular sku is a simple product and is not visible on the front-end, orders for this sku can only be placed from the admin, so that's why I'm using the `adminhtml` scope.  I went ahead and tried `global` and have the same result of 2 emails, is there a different observer I should be using to only send once when the order is placed from the admin?